# What are the differences between a claim, a statement and a proposition?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

In logic, it seems like the words "claim", "statement" and "proposition" have the same meaning, i.e. *a sentence which can be true or false (but not both)*, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

In logic, is there any difference between the meaning of those words?

In math textbooks, *proposition* seem to mean what in logic textbooks would have mean *proven proposition*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In contemporary mathematical logic, we generally ignore some philosophical distinctions. My guess is that you do not mean "proposition" here as the label that sits beside some theorems in a book, and instead you mean it in a philosophical sense.

In this sense, a statement *expresses* a proposition, but the same proposition could be expressed by multiple statements. A theorem is then a statement that has been proved. Or is it a proposition that has been proved? You can see that there are many complications here.

The existence, or lack thereof, of abstract "propositions", independent of the sentences that express them, is an important topic in philosophy. So you may have encountered a book that takes a more philosophical approach and mentions the distinction. But, especially at first, you can likely just identify propositions with statements, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my take on this. A *statement* is indeed a sentence which can be true or false. A *proposition* is a statement that the author is proposing for further scrutiny, possibly a proof. A *claim* is a proposition that the author claims is true. The differences are merely subtle characterizations by the author -- all are statements.

Prior to the edit, you mentioned *theorem*, so I'll elaborate further.

A *theorem* is a statement (including a proposition or claim) that has been proven true (or sometimes one that is very soon to be proven true). A *corollary* is a theorem that follows in a obvious or simple way from another theorem. A *lemma* is a theorem that is very useful in the proof of another theorem or theorems. Again, the differences are characterizations by the author -- all are theorems.

Comment: This is the easiest and convincing explanation I have seen so far. Thank you @joeA and of course Carl's answer

Answer (score 1):

A sentence is a statement that expresses a proposition or claim. Statements are employed to make propositions, which can be made of a sentence or a combination of sentences.

Comment: Not every sentence is a statement. Usually, sentences are not required to have truth values, whereas _statements_ are declarative sentences capable of being either true or false. For example, "logic is cool" is a sentence, but does not have a truth value and so does not qualify as a statement.

Answer (score 0):

According to many books about `Logic`, and in the context of `Logic`, which neighbours the `Mathematics` in the context of your question:

`Claim`==`Statement`==`Proposition`

The are used interchangeably, they mean same.